# Add further grouping to nomenclature using {nomencl} + {etoolbox}

Tags: etoolbox, nomenclature, grouping, nomencl

To add a nomenclature to my master thesis I follow [overleaf's recommendation](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Nomenclatures) and use below code.

Grouping is quite important for me. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to create subgroups by using `etoolbox`. With subgroups, for this particular example, I mean subsections of "Physics constants", "Number sets", and "Other symbols".

My overall goal is sth. like this: For a section (grouping) "List of Formulae and Symbols" there are subsections "Spaces and $\sigma$-Algebras", "Operators", "Functions", ...

How can I achieve this by extending below code snippet?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

%% This code creates the groups
% -----------------------------------------
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{P}{Physics constants}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{N}{Number sets}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{O}{Other symbols}{}}}%
]}
% -----------------------------------------

\begin{document}
Here is an example:

\nomenclature[P]{\(c\)}{Speed of light in a vacuum}
\nomenclature[P]{\(h\)}{Planck constant}
\nomenclature[P]{\(G\)}{Gravitational constant}
\nomenclature[N]{\(\mathbb{R}\)}{Real numbers}
\nomenclature[N]{\(\mathbb{C}\)}{Complex numbers}
\nomenclature[N]{\(\mathbb{H}\)}{Quaternions}
\nomenclature[O]{\(V\)}{Constant volume}
\nomenclature[O]{\(\rho\)}{Friction index}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays there's a better tool for such string switch commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of formulas and symbols}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\strcase}{mm}
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
    \strcase{#1}{
      {S}{Spaces and \(\sigma\)-algebras}
      {O}{Operators}
      {F}{Functions}
      % add here other cases
    }%
  ]%
}

\begin{document}

Here is an example:

\nomenclature[S]{\(V\)}{a vector space}
\nomenclature[S]{\(\mathcal{A}\)}{a \(\sigma\)-algebra}
\nomenclature[O]{\(\mathrm{T}\)}{an operator}
\nomenclature[O]{\(\Sigma\)}{an operator}
\nomenclature[F]{\(f\)}{a function}
\nomenclature[F]{\(\log\)}{the natural logarithm}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

You can easily extend the set of groups.

[image]